# Invoke a function when my class' methods trow an exception

Tags: powershell, class

I have the following code :

```
Class MyClass {

  [AnotherClass] myInstance

  A(){
    myInstance.myFirstFunction($a, $b, $c)
  }

  B(){
    myInstance.mySecondFunction($d, $e)
  }

}
```

Each time I call the a method from the AnotherClass object, this one can throw on exception (in the backend, it is a timeout for an external service that forces me to refresh the connection).

What I would like each time a method of the "MyClass" class throws a specific exception, handle that one with an internal private method that will do some task (hence, refresh the connection).

Is it possible to do that? Like an excpetion handler you can do with SpringBoot in java?

If it is not can I refactor the code so that I will only call on private method in the MyClass class, passing the function and the parameter I want to call the myInstance instance with? Something like:

```
Class MyClass {

  [AnotherClass] myInstance

  A(){
    myHandler("myFirstFunction", @($a, $b, $c))
  }

  B(){
    myHandler("mySecondFunction", @($d, $e))
  }

  myHandler($name, $params){
    try{
      $this.myInstance.$name($param)
    } catch {
      $this.myInstance.refreshConnection();
    }

  }

}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If your question is, can you use `try` / `catch` / `finally` in a PowerShell method, the answer is yes.

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking for, I'm sorry for my english. The question would be : can I call a class method with method name in a variable and parameters in another variable ? So that I can refactor en centralize in my code a only place where I can put that try catch?

Otherwise, I would have to surrend every call of a myInstance method, hence in method A, method B, method C, ...

Thank you!

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, you want to pass the invoked method name and same arguments to your handler and in there handle every type of exception. If that's the case, not sure if this could be possible in PowerShell but also it could be much easier to just have your class throw errors and catch them outside in your script and then recall the methods if needed (basically, error handling is much easier outside your class methods, be it in a function or script, etc)

Comment: Hi Santiago, thanks you for your help! I totally understand what you mean, I agree that error handling has a better place outside a class. Maybe I can give your more information about the context : my class is a kind of "Facade" Design Pattern for an external REST API service. After a random time, the Authentication you can have with the API expired and you need to regenerate a new token. I want the class to be a full encapsulation of that mechanism, so much so that if an exception is throw and a token must be regen, the class handle it on its own ^^

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track; here's a simple, self-contained example [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes):

```bash
Class MyClass {

  # The wrapped object.
  [string] $myInstance = 'foo-bar-baz'

  [object] A() {
    return $this.myHandler('Split', @('-'))
  }

  [object] B() {
    return $this.B(2)
  }
  [object] B([int] $count) {
    return $this.myHandler('Split', @('-', $count))
  }

  # Hidden helper method that invokes the specified
  # method with the specified arguments and handles exceptions.
  hidden [object] myHandler($name, $params) {
    try {
      return $this.myInstance.$name.Invoke($params)
    } catch {
      # ... handle the exception
      Write-Verbose -Verbose "An exception occurred: $_"
      return $null
    }
  }

}
```

Sample calls:

```bash
$o=[MyClass]::new()

$o.A() # -> 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
$o.B() # -> 'foo', 'bar-baz'
$o.B(-1) # -> exception, handled internally
```

Note:

- The above relies on PowerShell's ability to *reflect* on a method *without invoking it*, if you access it *without `()`*; e.g.:

  ```bash
  'foo'.Split # lists the overloads of the string type's .Split() method
  ```
- Doing so returns a [`System.Management.Automation.PSMethod`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSMethod)instance, which has an [`.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmethod.invoke) method to which you can pass an *array* of arguments; e.g., the following two calls are equivalent:

  ```bash
  # Regular method call -> 'foo', 'bar-baz'
  'foo-bar-baz'.Split('-', 2)

  # Equivalent call, via reflection.
  $methodName = 'Split'; $paramVals = @('-', 2) 
  'foo-bar-baz'.$methodName.Invoke($paramVals)
  ```

Therefore, in the `class` definition above, you could alternatively pass `$this.myInstance.Split` to the `myHandler()` method and call `.Invoke()` directly on it.
In terms of *performance*, this probably won't make a difference, but if you're using Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell extension, you'll benefit from *IntelliSense*; here's a simplified example:

```bash
& { 
  param($method, $paramVals)
  $method.Invoke($paramVals) 
}  'foo-bar-baz'.Split  @('-', 2)
```

Comment: Holy crap man, the .Invoke($params) function is exactly what I was missing! Thanks a lot for your help, I wish you a good day :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped, @PaulThirozier; my pleasure. I've added an explanation to the answer.